# ¿Como puedo ejecutar una consulta Mysql dentro de una función javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax, sql

En la función que se describe, deseo ejecutar una consulta a la base de datos en php, pero he de pasarle las variables de JS a PHP para ejecutarla y una vez se obtenga el dato solicitado, lo devuelva en JS. Por lo que he leido, esto no es posible directamente ejecutando código php dentro de java, puesto que el primero trabaja en el servidor y el segundo en el lado del cliente por lo que habría que hacerlo con Ajax . Lo que he comprobado es, si en el "where", pongo los valores a mano si me realiza la consulta. ¿Existe alguna otra manera?, y si no es posible como debería proceder. Gracias por la ayuda.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
function comprobar_nosoc(dninosocio){
     var dninosoc= dninosocio; 
     var vnumconv= document.getElementById("num_conv").value; // viene del formulario html
  var vdni= document.getElementById("dni").value;  // viene del formulario html
<?php 
      $dninosoc = $_POST["dninosoc"];
     $dni = $_POST["vdni"];
     $numconv = $_POST["vnumconv"];
         
$sqlNosoc = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM   PRU_Nosocios
         WHERE numconv ='$numconv' 
         and dni_socio = '$dni'
         and dni_nosocio= '$dninosoc'
         and situac='A' "); 
           $NumNosoc = mysqli_num_rows ($sqlNosoc);
           $rowNosoc = mysqli_fetch_array($sqlNosoc);
           mysqli_data_seek ($sqlNosoc, 0);             ?>
var vexisten = "<?php echo $NumNosoc; ?>";
return vexisten;
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Pasar de JS a PHP no es posible, pero de PHP a JS si, que por cierto te recomiendo al 100% que desacoples el cliente del servidor, a corto plazo puede parecerte mas facil y comodo trabajar con ambos en un mismo lado, pero a largo plazo esto no solo conlleva problemas de seguridad, rendimiento y mantenibilidad graves. Es preferible que ya de una vez desacoples el el frontend del backend, de lo contrario habra un completo caos mas adelante.

Comment: Nope no existe mas formas que usar ajax o, no usar ajax y enviar los datos por medio de un formulario normal ya sea con POST o con GET y recoger los datos con PHP enviados en el formulario hacia la misma pagina, pero si no usas ajax entonces para enviar los datos se tendria que recargar la pagina. de resto no existen mas formas de pasar una variable de JS a PHP.

Comment: Entendido, podrías indicarme un ejemplo trabajando sobre el código dado. Supongo que tendría que crear un archivo.php en el servidor y en él llevar el código php de la consulta y luego recoger las variables mediante post. ¿pero como llamo a ejecutar desde la función el archivo.php y como llevo desde el php los resultados de la consulta otra vez a la funcíón?.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que debes o deberias hacer es separar el frontend de tu backend, lo segundo es que podrias usar ajax para lo que necesitas, aquí un ejemplo de ajax que he creado para tu caso:

Este es el **html**, yo por defecto le coloque enrealidad extension de php, pero igual deberia funcionar sin necesidad de ser un archivo php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Ajax</title>
    <script src="ajax-test.js"></script>
</head>
<body>



</body>
</html>
```

**Javascript:**

```
window.onload = ()=>{

    const serverUrl = encodeURI('http://localhost/Prueba Ajax/formulario-ajax.php');
    const ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    const datosAEnviar = new FormData();

    /*
        Form data es algo como esto: [{llave: valor}, ...];
        el metodo append toma como primer parametro la llave
        y como segundo el valor, en pocas palabras es un array
        de objetos.
    */

    datosAEnviar.append('dato1', 'X');
    datosAEnviar.append('dato2', true);
    datosAEnviar.append('dato3', 10);

    //Cuando carga la petición podemos extraer los datos.
    ajax.onload = ()=>{

        const response = JSON.parse(ajax.response);
        console.log(response);

    }

    ajax.onreadystatechange = ()=>{

        /*
            Aquí se escucha a los cambios de la petición ajax una vez hecha la petición,
            el estado 200 significa que no ha habido ningun problema al realizar 
            la petición ajax, es decir, la petición fue entregada y realizada de
            manera correcta.

            para el caso de ready state, estan los siguientes estados:

            2: Peticion recibida
            3: Peticion siendo procesada
            4: Peticion finalizada y respuesta lista

            importante notar que esta función puede ejecutarse varias vecez
            dependiendo de los cambios de estado, por esta razón es indispensable
            que compruebes que el readyState sea 4.
        */
        if(ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200){
            /*
                funciones y cosas a realizar cuando la petición este
                lista.
            */
        }

    };

    ajax.open('POST', serverUrl);
    ajax.send(datosAEnviar); 

}
```

Archivo **php** que recibe los datos los procesa y los envia a la misma pagina con ajax:

```
<?php

    header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');

    $dato1 = $_POST["dato1"];
    $dato2 = $_POST["dato2"];
    $dato3 = $_POST["dato3"];

    /*
        Puedes enviar información como un json a javascript
        de esta manera:
    */
    $respuesta = json_encode(
        [
            "datoRespuesta1" => "OK",
            "datoRespuesta2" => [$dato1, $dato2, $dato3],
            "datoRespuesta3" => 10,
            "datoRespuesta4" => "lo que sea..."
        ]
    );

    echo $respuesta;

?>
```

Aquí en esta parte de aquí:

```
//Cuando carga la petición podemos extraer los datos.
ajax.onload = ()=>{

    const response = JSON.parse(ajax.response);
    console.log(response);

}
```

Dentro del onload es donde podrias mezclar código de javascript con php como lo tenias previsto, incluso si quieres puedes funcionalizar este ejemplo y simplemente devolver la respuesta para luego usarla en otra parte, es mas si quieres hasta podrias crear una clase que se encargue de crear y cargar información por medio de ajax. Sin embargo, esto es realmente todo lo que requieres para tu proposito, espero sea de ayuda, saludos.

Comment: Ah se me olvida una cosa, si quieres funcionificar este ejemplo te recomiendo que mires algo sobre los temas: async await y promesas, sobre todo lo de las promesas, ya que ajax es asincrono, si quieres funcionificarlo, en caso de que realmente no entiendas estos 3 ultimos temas puedo editar la respuesta y funcionificarla para poder que puedas usar los contenidos traidos por ajax a manera de promise o desde await, si funcionalizas así nada mas el código y retornas la respuesta cuando se carga la petición lo mas probale es que obtengas undefined, las promises solucionan esto.

Comment: Gracias Riven, intentaré implementarlo en mi código, el problema de separar el front del back es estos momentos es que tengo demasiado código escrito. El  formulario que he puesto es a modo de ejemplo para exponer el problema , el real mezcla campos fijos y tablas dinámicas cuyos campos son validados llamando a funciones en javascript y son muchas, tiraría en trabajo de muchas horas a la basura. De todas formas muchas gracias amigo, como te digo extraeré y aplicaré tu solución en aquello que me sea factible en estos momentos.

Answer (score 1):

Presento mi solución sin perjuicio de las recomendaciones y sugerencias expuestas.

JavaScript

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    function pregunta_Validar_Campos(){
      function comprobar_nosoc(dninosocio){
   // Traemos los valores de variables del formulario 
                vdni = document.getElementById("dni").value;
                vnumconv = document.getElementById("numconv").value;
                var parametros = {                     
                "dni" : vdni,
                "numconv" : vnumconv,
            "dninosocio" : dninosocio
                 };
   
// enviamos al archivo.php con ajax    
$.ajax({
       data:  parametros, 
       url:   "https://www.mipaginaweb.es/Archivo.php", 
      type:  "post", 
 beforeSend: function () {
 $("#resultado").html("Procesando, espere por favor...");},
 success:  function (response) { 
 $("#resultado").html(response);// resultado de la consulta al php`
                }
        });
   return 0;  // retorna el valor para validación 
    } 

// Aqui recorro el Array de validación mediante un for el cual omito.
// Los valores del array bidimensional corresponden a una tabla dinámica que omito

if ( aArray[2][i] !="A")
       { dninosocio= aArray[1][i];                   
           resultado= comprobar_nosoc(dninosocio) ;   // ejecuto la funcion y envio el dato 
            if (resultado == 0)  // recojo el resultado de la consulta 
            {alert('[ERROR_07]\ No existe invitado!!!');
             document.Actualizar.aArray[2][i].focus()
            return 0;}  
   
         } 
        }  
     } 
 
 if (confirm('Los datos serán guardados en la Base de Datos de SENDA. ¿Estás seguro de realizar esta acción?'))
    {document.Actualizar.submit()} 

   } 

</script>
```

HTML Formulario

```html
<form name="Actualizar" action="https://www.sendatoledo.es/a_ConfNosoc_PRU.php"  method="POST">
<input Numero Conv: name="numconv" id="numconv" type="text" value="2020-000"></p> 
<input Dni socio: name ="dni" id="dni" type="text" value="70640538V"></p>

<table border="1" class="table" id="tablainvitados">
      // aqui viene la tabla 
</table>
<button type="button"  onclick="pregunta_Validar_Campos()">Actualizar Datos</button>
</form>
```

Archivo.PHP para hacer la consulta

```html
<?php
include("conexion.php");
 $tildes = $con->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'"); //Para que se muestren las tildes
                     $dni= $_POST["vdni"];
                  $numconv  = $_POST["vnumconv"];
                     $dninosocio = $_POST["dninosocio"];

$sqlNosoc = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM ArchivoBaseDatos
         WHERE numconv ='$numconv' 
         and dni_socio = '$dni'
         and dni_nosocio= '$dninosocio'
         and situac='A' "); 
           $NumNosoc = mysqli_num_rows ($sqlNosoc);
           $rowNosoc = mysqli_fetch_array($sqlNosoc);
           mysqli_data_seek ($sqlNosoc, 0);     

$resultado = $NumNosoc;

echo $resultado;  //haciendo este echo estas respondiendo la solicitud ajax

?>
```

Espero que a alguien le sirva